# Adding stereo controls to a steering wheel not designed for that purpose

Tags: steering-wheel, audio

I own a **Fiat Panda** from 2004. Its interiors look very similar to this picture:

http://autopicone.altervista.org/blog/wp-content/gallery/fiat_panda/1282644967_115464950_1-zdjecia-fiat-panda-2004r-gaz-1282644967.jpg

As you can see, the steering wheel has no control buttons for the stereo.

**Is it possible to add stereo controls to the steering wheel of a car that doesn't have this feature?**

Sub-questions:

- Would this require replacing the wheel entirely, or are there any "add-on" solutions?
- Is it necessary for the mounted car stereo to have explicit support and compatibility with this feature for potential solutions to work?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is fairly common place with aftermarket stereo systems. Look at this example from [Crutchfield](http://www.crutchfield.com/p_120RFASWC/Axxess-RFASWC-Universal-Steering-Wheel-Control-Interface.html?tp=3405):

[image]

I don't know much about them, other than that they exist. They do not in anyway modify your steering, just add a way to access controls at your fingertips.

Comment: Are these made to be attached to the wheel, or do they require the wheel to have a socket for them?

Comment: I am sure universal means universal. Look at the specs online. I was just trying to give you confirmation and also ideas.

Answer (score 0):

in most countries any modification particularly one that may impact upon steering 
would be frowned upon.Invest in a voice activated stereo that can be coded to your
voice only making theft pointless